# Actualizar un solo campo de una tabla de acces desde c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

Tengo una duda acerca del metodo de actualizar un registro pues estoy guardando los datos en un archivo de acces y al hacer todas las funciones que he realizado funcionan correctamente pero me pregunto como puedo hacer para que al momento de actualizar y solo haber llenado un solo texbox
solo se modifique el campo correspondiente en acces y los de más que ya contengan algun datos no cambien su valor a 0 por la función string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace  ¿existe alguna funcion que realice esto? espero puedan ayudarme
de antemano muchas gracias.
**Ejemplo**:

```
id Nombre Clabe   C1  C2 
1  juan   2020A   3   3
```

**quiero Modificar c1**

```
id Nombre Clabe   C1  C2 
1  juan   2020A   1   3
```

**ya que la funcion " string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace"
la use para solo ingresar algunos valores y devolveria esto**

```
id Nombre Clabe   C1  C2 
1    0      0      1   0
```

**Metodo para actualizar**

```
public string Actualizar(ALUMNO p)
        {
           string Act = p.Periodo;
            switch (Act)
            {
                case "1° PARCIAL":
                    
                    break;
                case "2° PARCIAL":
                    break;
                case "3° PARCIAL":
                    break;

            }

            bool bandera = true;
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            string mensaje = "";
            cmd.CommandText = string.Format
      ("update TablaAlumnos set " +
        "CLABE = '{0}',NOMBRE= '{1}', C1 = {2},C2= {3}, C3 = {4},C4= {5}, R1 = {6},H1= {7}, H2 = {8},H3= {9}, H4 = {10},R2= {11}, ACTYVAL1 = {12},ACTYVAL2= {13}, ACTYVAL3 = {14},ACTYVAL4= {15}, R3 = {16},DES1= {17}, DES2 = {18},DES3= {19}, DES4 = {20},R4= {21}, SUMA = {22},COMP_ADQ= '{23}'," +
        " INA={24}  where Id = {25}"
      , p.CLABE, p.NOMBRE, p.C1, p.C2, p.C3, p.C4, p.R1, p.H1, p.H2, p.H3, p.H4, p.R2, p.ACTYVAL1, p.ACTYVAL2, p.ACTYVAL3, p.ACTYVAL4, p.R3, p.DES1, p.DES2, p.DES3, p.DES4, p.R4, p.SUMA, p.COMP_ADQ, p.INA, p.Id);

            cmd.Connection = cn;
            try
            {
                cn.Open();
                if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                    bandera = true;
                mensaje = "Registro actualizado";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                mensaje = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                cn.Close();
            }
            return mensaje;
        }
```

**Evento del botón**

```
private void btnActualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ALUMNO p = new ALUMNO();

                p.Id = Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text);
                p.CLABE = this.txtNombre.Text;
                p.NOMBRE = this.txtClabe.Text;

                // p.C1 = int.Parse(txtCon1.Text);
                p.C1 = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCon1.Text)) ? Convert.ToInt32(txtCon1.Text) : 0;
                //p.C2 = int.Parse(txtCon2.Text);
                p.C2 = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCon2.Text)) ? Convert.ToInt32(txtCon2.Text) : 0;
                // p.C3 = int.Parse(txtCon3.Text);
                p.C3 = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCon3.Text)) ? Convert.ToInt32(txtCon3.Text) : 0;
                //p.C4 = int.Parse(txtCon4.Text);
                p.C4 = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCon4.Text)) ? Convert.ToInt32(txtCon4.Text) : 0;
                p.R1 = Convert.ToInt32(p.C1 + p.C2 + p.C3 + p.C4);

                //p.H1 = int.Parse(txtHab1.Text);
                p.H1 = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtHab1.Text)) ? Convert.ToInt32(txtHab1.Text) : 0;
                //p.H2 = int.Parse(txtHab2.Text);
                p.H2 = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtHab2.Text)) ? Convert.ToInt32(txtHab2.Text) : 0;
                //p.H3 = int.Parse(txtHab3.Text);
                p.H3 = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtHab3.Text)) ? Convert.ToInt32(txtHab3.Text) : 0;
                //p.H4 = int.Parse(txtHab4.Text);
                p.H4 = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtHab4.Text)) ? Convert.ToInt32(txtHab4.Text) : 0;
                p.R2 = Convert.ToInt32(p.H1 + p.H2 + p.H3 + p.H4);

                //p.ACTYVAL1 = int.Parse(txtAct1.Text);
                p.ACTYVAL1 = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtAct1.Text)) ? Convert.ToInt32(txtAct1.Text) : 0;
                //p.ACTYVAL2 = int.Parse(txtAct2.Text);
                p.ACTYVAL2 = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtAct2.Text)) ? Convert.ToInt32(txtAct2.Text) : 0;
                //p.ACTYVAL3 = int.Parse(txtAct3.Text);
                p.ACTYVAL3 = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtAct3.Text)) ? Convert.ToInt32(txtAct3.Text) : 0;
                //p.ACTYVAL4 = int.Parse(txtAct4.Text);
                p.ACTYVAL4 = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtAct4.Text)) ? Convert.ToInt32(txtAct4.Text) : 0;
                p.R3 = Convert.ToInt32(p.ACTYVAL1 + p.ACTYVAL2 + p.ACTYVAL3 + p.ACTYVAL4);

                //p.DES1 = int.Parse(txtDes1.Text);
                p.DES1 = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtDes1.Text)) ? Convert.ToInt32(txtDes1.Text) : 0;
                // p.DES2 = int.Parse(txtDes2.Text);
                p.DES2 = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtDes2.Text)) ? Convert.ToInt32(txtDes2.Text) : 0;
                //p.DES3 = int.Parse(txtDes3.Text);
                p.DES3 = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtDes3.Text)) ? Convert.ToInt32(txtDes3.Text) : 0;
                //p.DES4 = int.Parse(txtDes4.Text);
                p.DES4 = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtDes4.Text)) ? Convert.ToInt32(txtDes4.Text) : 0;
                p.R4 = Convert.ToInt32(p.DES1 + p.DES2 + p.DES3 + p.DES4);

                p.SUMA = p.R1 + p.R2 + p.R3 + p.R4;

                p.COMP_ADQ = txtComp.Text.ToString();

                p.INA = 10;

                p.Periodo = cbPeriodo.Text;
                if (crud.Actualizar(p).Equals("registro Actualizado correctamente"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(crud.Actualizar(p));
                    llenargrid();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(crud.Actualizar(p));
                    llenargrid();
                }
            }
           catch (Exception)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Ingreso algun valor desconocido o faltan campos por llenar");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Deja ver si te entendi, tu lo que quieres es actualizar en tu base de datos la informacion del textbox que se llenó o los textboxes que se llenaron, el que no se llenó se asume que no se va a actualizar esa información en la base de datos?

Answer (score 1):

Si obviamos que los nombres de esas columnas no son óptimos, que la consulta sería completamente vulnerable a inyección SQL, y muchas otras cosas más, lo que YO haría, si no tuviese otro remedio, sería:

1. A los `TextBox` les daría el **nombre de la columna en la base de datos**. En lugar de llamarse `txtHab3`, su nombre sería `Hab3`. Igual, a mucha gente le parece algo arcaica la notación Húngara. De esta manera puedo traerme todos los controles de tipo texto y recorrerlos uno por uno para:
2. **Armar el update de forma dinámica**. No existe una función que haga lo que pidas. Bueno tal vez. En REST existe el PATCH. Sugiero lo investigues aunque aquí probablemente no aplique.

En código sería algo así

```
var stringList = new List<string>();

        foreach (Control control in Controls)
        {
            if (control is TextBox && int.TryParse(control.Text, out _))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(control.Text))
                {
                    stringList.Add($" {control.Name} = {control.Text} ");
                }
            }
        }

 var updateString = string.Join(",", stringList);
```

Esto va a obtener todos los TextBox que no estén vacíos y su número pueda ser convertido a entero. Luego los agrega a una lista de strings, y con el Join les agrega una coma para ser utilizados en la cláusula `SET` de tu sql.

[image: Prueba en mi local]

Resultado de updateString:

```
  Calificacion5 = 50 , Calificacion3 = 25 , Calificacion1 = 0
```

Te toca a tí el resto de validaciones y el resto de la query. Suerte.